# Do not share same socket between two threads at the same time

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, concurrency, zeromq

I have a code in which I am dealing with sockets and I need to make sure that I don't **share same socket between two threads**. In my below code, I have a background thread which runs every 60 seconds and calls `updateLiveSockets()` method. In the `updateLiveSockets()` method, I iterate all the sockets I have and then start pinging them one by one by calling `execute` method of `SendToSocket` class and basis on the response I mark them as live or dead.

Now all the reader threads will call `getNextSocket()` method concurrently to get the next live available socket so it has to be thread safe and I need to make sure all the reader threads should see the same consitent state of `SocketHolder` and `Socket`.

Below is my `SocketManager` class:

```
public class SocketManager {
  private static final Random random = new Random();
  private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
  private final Map<Datacenters, List<SocketHolder>> liveSocketsByDatacenter =
      new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
  private final ZContext ctx = new ZContext();

  // ...

  private SocketManager() {
    connectToZMQSockets();
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(this::updateLiveSockets, 60, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  // during startup, making a connection and populate once
  private void connectToZMQSockets() {
    Map<Datacenters, List<String>> socketsByDatacenter = Utils.SERVERS;
    for (Map.Entry<Datacenters, List<String>> entry : socketsByDatacenter.entrySet()) {
      List<SocketHolder> addedColoSockets = connect(entry.getValue(), ZMQ.PUSH);
      liveSocketsByDatacenter.put(entry.getKey(), addedColoSockets);
    }
  }

  private List<SocketHolder> connect(List<String> paddes, int socketType) {
    List<SocketHolder> socketList = new ArrayList<>();
    // ....
    return socketList;
  }

  // this method will be called by multiple threads concurrently to get the next live socket
  // is there any concurrency or thread safety issue or race condition here?
  public Optional<SocketHolder> getNextSocket() {
    for (Datacenters dc : Datacenters.getOrderedDatacenters()) {
      Optional<SocketHolder> liveSocket = getLiveSocket(liveSocketsByDatacenter.get(dc));
      if (liveSocket.isPresent()) {
        return liveSocket;
      }
    }
    return Optional.absent();
  }

  private Optional<SocketHolder> getLiveSocket(final List<SocketHolder> listOfEndPoints) {
    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(listOfEndPoints)) {
      // The list of live sockets
      List<SocketHolder> liveOnly = new ArrayList<>(listOfEndPoints.size());
      for (SocketHolder obj : listOfEndPoints) {
        if (obj.isLive()) {
          liveOnly.add(obj);
        }
      }
      if (!liveOnly.isEmpty()) {
        // The list is not empty so we shuffle it an return the first element
        return Optional.of(liveOnly.get(random.nextInt(liveOnly.size()))); // just pick one
      }
    }
    return Optional.absent();
  }

  // runs every 60 seconds to ping all the socket to make sure whether they are alive or not
  private void updateLiveSockets() {
    Map<Datacenters, List<String>> socketsByDatacenter = Utils.SERVERS;

    for (Map.Entry<Datacenters, List<String>> entry : socketsByDatacenter.entrySet()) {
      List<SocketHolder> liveSockets = liveSocketsByDatacenter.get(entry.getKey());
      List<SocketHolder> liveUpdatedSockets = new ArrayList<>();
      for (SocketHolder liveSocket : liveSockets) {
        Socket socket = liveSocket.getSocket();
        String endpoint = liveSocket.getEndpoint();
        Map<byte[], byte[]> holder = populateMap();
        Message message = new Message(holder, Partition.COMMAND);

        // pinging to see whether a socket is live or not
        boolean status = SendToSocket.getInstance().execute(message.getAdd(), holder, socket);
        boolean isLive = (status) ? true : false;

        SocketHolder zmq = new SocketHolder(socket, liveSocket.getContext(), endpoint, isLive);
        liveUpdatedSockets.add(zmq);
      }
      liveSocketsByDatacenter.put(entry.getKey(), Collections.unmodifiableList(liveUpdatedSockets));
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my `SendToSocket` class:

```
// as of now this is only called by "SocketManager" class
public boolean execute(final long padd, final byte[] holder, final Socket socket) {
    boolean sent = sendAsync(padd, encRed, socket, true);
    // if the record was sent successfully, then only sleep for timeout period
    if (sent) {
      try {
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      }
    }
    return sent;
}

public boolean sendAsync(final long padd, final byte[] encRed, final Socket socket,
  final boolean sockMess) {
    ZMsg msg = new ZMsg();
    msg.add(encRed);
    boolean sent = msg.send(socket);
    msg.destroy();
    retryQueue.put(padd, encRed);
    return sent;
}

// this method will be called by multiple threads concurrently
public boolean sendAsync(final long addr, final byte[] reco) {
  Optional<SocketHolder> liveSockets = SocketManager.getInstance().getNextSocket();
  return sendAsync(addr, reco, liveSockets.get().getSocket(), false);
}
```

**Problem Statement**

Now as you can see that I am sharing same socket between two threads. It seems `getNextSocket()` could return a `0MQ socket` to `thread A`. Concurrently, the `timer thread` may access the same `0MQ socket` to ping it. In this case `thread A` and the `timer thread` are mutating the same `0MQ socket`, which can lead to problems. So I am trying to find a way so that I can prevent different threads from sending data to the same socket at the same time and mucking up my data.

So I decided to synchronize the socket so that no two threads can access at the same time. Below is the change I made in `updateLiveSockets` method. I synchronized on the socket in below method:

```
  // runs every 60 seconds to ping all the socket to make sure whether they are alive or not
  private void updateLiveSockets() {
    Map<Datacenters, List<String>> socketsByDatacenter = Utils.SERVERS;

    for (Map.Entry<Datacenters, List<String>> entry : socketsByDatacenter.entrySet()) {
      List<SocketHolder> liveSockets = liveSocketsByDatacenter.get(entry.getKey());
      List<SocketHolder> liveUpdatedSockets = new ArrayList<>();
      for (SocketHolder liveSocket : liveSockets) {
        Socket socket = liveSocket.getSocket();
        String endpoint = liveSocket.getEndpoint();
        Map<byte[], byte[]> holder = populateMap();
        Message message = new Message(holder, Partition.COMMAND);

        // using the socket as its own lock
        synchronized (socket) {
            // pinging to see whether a socket is live or not
            boolean status = SendToSocket.getInstance().execute(message.getAdd(), holder, socket);
            boolean isLive = (status) ? true : false;

            SocketHolder zmq = new SocketHolder(socket, liveSocket.getContext(), endpoint, isLive);
            liveUpdatedSockets.add(zmq);
        }
      }
      liveSocketsByDatacenter.put(entry.getKey(), Collections.unmodifiableList(liveUpdatedSockets));
    }
  }
```

And below is the change I made in `sendAsync` method. In this also I synchronized on socket before sending on it.

```
public boolean sendAsync(final long padd, final byte[] encRed, final Socket socket,
  final boolean sockMess) {
    ZMsg msg = new ZMsg();
    msg.add(encRed);
    // again, using the socket as its own lock while accessing it
    boolean sent;
    synchronized (socket) {
        sent = msg.send(socket);
    }
    msg.destroy();
    retryQueue.put(padd, encRed);
    return sent;
}
```

What is the best way by which I can make sure that I am not sharing same sockets between two threads? In general I have around 60 sockets and 20 threads accessing those sockets. I have my above code working fine so opting for a code review to see if there is any better or efficient way to do the same thing? Also is there any corner case or edge case that I have missed which can lead to some bug?

If many threads use the same socket, resources aren't well utilized. Moreover If `msg.send(socket);` is blocked (technically it shouldn't) all threads waiting for this socket are blocked. So I guess there might be a better way to ensure that every thread uses a different single live socket at the same time instead of synchronization on a particular socket.

Comment: soo ... you're basically reinventing [`ThreadLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/ThreadLocal.html)?

Comment: I have never used `ThreadLocal` before. Interesting thing. How can I apply it here then?

Comment: You could use a concurrent queue that supports 1 writer and multiple readers and have getLiveSockets enqueue to it and the threads dequeue the sockets from it

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Feel free to post a follow-up question instead.

Answer (score 5):

Let's start with the "easy" stuff:

- `(status) ? true : false` is just `status` (in `updateLiveSockets`)
- And while we're there: `status` is only used to assign to `isLive`. Skip that intermediary and assign directly to `isLive`
- `CollectionUtils.isEmpty(listOfEndPoints)` reads much easier as `listOfEndpoints.isEmpty()`. If that's not semantically the same, `isEmpty` desperately needs a rename.
- The code you show only uses `scheduler` in `SocketManager`'s constructor. If you want to ever be able to clean your threads up, you need to expose a method that can end the scheduler's execution. Alternatively you could make the `scheduler` use "daemon"-threads, which don't prevent the JVM from shutting down.
- The message from `sendAsync` is put into the `retryQueue` (which is not defined in the code you show) in all cases. That's most likely wrong.
- The name `sendAsync` is misleading, because the method is decidedly **not** asynchronous. Either change the name, or make the method actually async...
- The pluralization in all the code is a **mess**. If you can't even narrow down the name of the variables into a singular, how do you expect to keep track of singular socket(s) across threads?
- You're overusing `Optional` in the `SocketManager` and ignoring it in the calling code. Optional does not provide any safety in your happy-path and it will still blow the code to smithereens in `liveSockets.get().getSocket()` if the `liveSockets` is `Optional.absent()`. Because `get` **will** throw an exception and at that point you could've just stuck with standard `null` and get a `NullPointerException`....
- `SocketManager` connects to ZMQ sockets on instantiation. That's **bad**. I've explained why in an [unrelated answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/157176/37660), the gist is: It's a bad idea to perform I/O and other long-running things as well as features of the public API of a class on instantiation, because it's not the expected behaviour of a constructor to do so.
- A lot of the code presented here can be rewritten using `Stream`s Consider `getNextSocket()`:

  ```
  public Optional<SocketHolder> getNextSocket() {
      return DataCenters.getOrderedDatacenters()
          .stream()
          .map(dc -> getLiveSocket(liveSocketsByDatacenter.get(dc)))
          .filter(Optional::isPresent)
          .first();
  }
  ```

  Similar ideas apply for basically all the methods in `SocketManager`.

After this is fixed, I might be able to follow the "narrative" of your code well enough to actually review it for correctness. As it stands I get too distracted and confused by how it's currently formulated :(

Comment: I am still working with Java 7. Pretty much what you suggested I think I have made those changes already after carefully looking at the code. I am more inclined in how we can avoid use of synchronization and have lock free solution for my case? As currently I am synchronizing on socket to prevent multiple threads from using it.